# UIDatePicker and UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uidatepicker

I want to show a text in `UITextView` depend on the date, some thing like "in This Day App", I have this code in action

```
-(void)changingText:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    NSDictionary *pageData = [[DataSource sharedDataSource] dataForPage:pageIndex];

    NSString *dateText = [pageData objectForKey:@"pageName"];

    NSString *dateInfo = [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    if ([dateText isEqualToString: dateInfo]) {
        myText.text = [pageData objectForKey:@"pageText"];
    }
    [df release];
}
```

My qustion is how to update `UITextView` With the data from `NSDictionery ForKey@"pageText"` , because it shows just the first object.

here is the Object that i want to triger when the date been selected.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        dataPages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Oct 3, 2009", @"pageName",
                      @"First Object", @"pageText",
                      nil],

                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Oct 10, 2009", @"pageName",
                      @"second Object", @"pageText",
                      nil],

                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Oct 27, 2009", @"pageName",
                      @"Third Object", @"pageText",
                      nil],                      
                     nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Ibrahim, could you indicate which programming language you are using, and add a tag for it?

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: DOK, programming language i am using is Objective-C
Vladimir, my Qustion is how to update UITextView With the data from NSDictionery ForKey@"pageText" , because it shows just the first object.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “the first object”?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I think you need to make the object from your dictionary into an NSString like this:

```
-(void)changingText:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    NSDictionary *pageData = [[DataSource sharedDataSource] dataForPage:pageIndex];
    NSString *dateText = (NSString *)[pageData objectForKey:@"pageName"];
    NSString *dateInfo = [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:dateInfo]];
    if ([dateText isEqualToString: dateInfo]) {
        myText.text = dateText;
    }

    [df release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks man , but the dame probel, it just triger the first Object, I added the Code to my qustion above,

Comment: What do you want the string in the text field to be?  "First Object, Second Object, Third Object"?

Comment: Also, where is pageIndex being set?